# golang: copy of context when copy is background

Tags: go

Related but not identical to: [Golang: How to copy Context object without deriving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348712/golang-how-to-copy-context-object-without-deriving)

Is it acceptable to derive a `context.WithTimeout` from a `context.Background()` and have the child be cancellable? We currently have this:

```
ctx = context.Background()
...
newCtx, cancelFunc = context.WithTimeout(ctx, someDuration)
...
os.exec.CommandContext(newCtx, myCmd).Run()
# via a signal handler: cancelFunc() // myCmd does not stop!!
```

That is, we derive a context withTimeout from a Background context, then we execute a command using `os.exec` in that context, but when we call `cancelFunc`, the `cmd` is not dying. I am wondering whether this relates to the exact wording of what it means to be a "copy". From: https://golang.org/pkg/context/

> WithTimeout returns WithDeadline(parent, time.Now().Add(timeout)).

> WithDeadline returns a **copy of the parent context** with the deadline adjusted to be no later than d. If the parent's deadline is already earlier than d, WithDeadline(parent, d) is semantically equivalent to parent. The returned context's Done channel is closed when the deadline expires, when the returned cancel function is called, or when the parent context's Done channel is closed, whichever happens first.

So question is, is Background a safe context to "copy" if you wish to cancel the copy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine to use `context.Background()` like this.

Your problem is that `CommandContext.Run()` waits for the command to finish before returning, so your `cancelFunc` can never cancel the execution of the command. You need to run the command in a goroutine (and synchronize your code on the termination of that goroutine), and then you'll be able to call `cancelFunc` effectively.

Here's a full working example (that uses the unix command `yes`, which means you'll have to adapt it if you're using an OS that doesn't have a `yes` command).

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    nctx, cancf := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 1000*time.Second)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        cmd := exec.CommandContext(nctx, "yes", "I am running")
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Run()
        fmt.Println("command done!")
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second / 100)
    cancf()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Note that this can produce a lot of output even though the command is cancelled after a sleep of 10ms.

Comment: our cancelFunc gets registered to a signal handler, which I didnt show originally, sorry

Comment: Yeah, so the question changed to involve a signal handler after I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23019

> If the subprocess C1 itself starts a subsubprocess C2, and if C1 passes any of its stdin/stdout/stderr descriptors to C2, and if C1 exits without waiting for C2 to exit, then C2 will hold an open end of the pipes created by the os/exec package. The (*Cmd).Wait method will wait until the goroutines complete, which means waiting until those pipes are closed, which in practice means waiting until C2 exits. This is confusing, because the user sees that C1 is done, and doesn't understand why their program is still waiting for it.

We have this exact golang issue. However I cannot delete my question since there is already an answer.